# Storing the path to folders and inner folders

Tags: python, path, filepath

i'm having difficulties trying to read from sub-folders that are inside a folder. What im trying to do is: i have my path `"C:\Dataset"` which has 2 folders inside them and inside both folders, i have person names that have pictures for example: `"C:\Dataset\Drunk\JohnDoe\Pic1"`, `"C:\Dataset\Sober\JaneDoe\Pic1"`. I want to be able to read each picture and store them in a path variable.

At the moment, what i got so far, basically, i get the images as long as they are inside Drunk and Sober only, for instance: `'C:\Dataset\Drunk\Pic1'`, and the code that i am using to do is this:

```py
DATADIR = "C:\Dataset"
CATEGORIES = ["Positive", "Negative"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_path = os.path.join(path,img)
        img_data = open(img_path, 'r').read()
        break
    break
```

Basically, what i am trying to do is that when i iterate inside Drunk folder it also iterates inside the inner folders, reading the path to the pictures that are in `C:\Dataset\Drunk\JohnDoe\nthPic`, `C:\Dataset\Drunk\JoeDoe\nthPic`, `C:\Dataset\Drunk and Sober \nthJoe\nthPic` `C:\Dataset\Drunk\JamesDoe\nthPic`. Therefore, when I do the reading, it grabs the whole folder map

This is basically what my goal is.

Comment: Can't you just retrieve all the images that are in your subdirectories (and the directories that lay below that) and just iterature over that? For instance, you can get all `png` files like this: `glob.glob('C:\Dataset/**/*.png',,recursive=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one nesting more:
It saves all images in the dictionary `images`, key is the full path.

```
DATADIR = "C:\Dataset"
CATEGORIES = ["Drunk", "Sober"]

images = {}

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    for person in os.listdir(path):
        personfolder = os.path.join(path, person):
        for imgname in os.listdir(personfolder):
            fullpath = os.path.join(personfolder, imgname)
            images[fullpath] = open(fullpath, 'r').read()
```